# Solved: How to link in a Swiper on a the right slide

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

I solved my problem with swiper js.

I am testing the Swiper JS. Now I would like to link from a  on my website, open a swiper in an overlay an show the right slide. The number of the slide should be a part of the link.

I would like to set the slide number with a foreach. by click on a link like
Swipe to slide 3 the swiper should start in an overlay on the right slide in an overlay. I would be really happy if you have a solution for this.

To concrete my wish hier some snippets

I have a list of links like

```
<a href="#" onclick="btn1()">1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="btn2()">2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="btn3()">3</a>
<a href="#" onclick="btn4()">4</a>
<a href="#" onclick="btn5()">5</a>
```

here is the slider

```
<!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">ProductDescription 1 Longform</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">ProductDescription 2 Longform</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">ProductDescription 3 Longform</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">ProductDescription 4 Longform</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">ProductDescription 5 Longform</div>

      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
```

this is the Javascript

```
   <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script>
      var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          type: "fraction",
        },
        navigation: {
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
      });

function btn1() { swiper.slideTo(0,false,false); }
function btn2() { swiper.slideTo(1,false,false); }
function btn3() { swiper.slideTo(2,false,false); }
function btn4() { swiper.slideTo(3,false,false); }
function btn5() { swiper.slideTo(4,false,false); } 

    </script>
```

I put in here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/biobastard/gqh78ezx/15/)

Comment: Hey, you should put the content of your answer into the question body to make it more clear.

Comment: thanks, did it. 
I have a solution for this if I use jquery lib. Is there any other solution without jquery?